# Extend outlook rules Actions using vsto

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I Want to create custom code that will run when the user decides based on outlook's rules.

so far i checked a few possibilities:

1)Create a custom Action that would be added to the rules actions options - that is not possible according to MS - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1bae2bbc-0ab4-419a-b0d6-7a02195348ce/outlook-custom-action-in-rules-wizard?forum=vsto

2)Run Script based on a rule - built in ability, however i encountered a few issues:

- it is not possible to share the script
- the macro's have to be enabled each time (disabled again when you restart)

I want to use the C# VSTO add-in in order to overcome those problems:
Is there a way to implant the script and make sure the macro is enabled using a VSTO add-in?

this way users will be able to install the add-in and then chose the script as an action to every rule they create based on the default outlook rules.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a rule if your code is in a VSTO addin. You can use `Items.ItemAdd` event on the Inbox folder or `Application.NewMailEx` event to so anything your please with the newly arrived message.

Comment: I understand that, but in order for that to be flexible It will require me to set my own window for defining the filters to when to act (basically I will need to redevelop the rules section). I want the user to be able to choose when to enact said code based on the existing rules section

Comment: which returns to the previous point can i implant a script to the client that installs my addin and enable the macro so he would use that with the rules (he will chose run a script and the script will appear in the scripts list?)

Comment: I don't think that will work - OOM won't let you create rules (only access existing ones using Store.GetRules). You can create server-side (Exchange) rules using Extended MAPI or Redemption, but client side actions are not supported.